# gmaven:execute can't find compiled class

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven

I'm attempting to use the gmaven-plugin to compile a class `com.kc.Validator` in *src/test/groovy/com/kc/Validator.groovy* and then run a script using the class.  After `mvn compile` the .class file is in *target/test-classes/com/kc but the script execution fails:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute (validate-configuration) on project solver2: startup failed, script1367530828433.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.kc.Validator
```

The relevant section of pom.xml is:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
<artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>compile-groovy</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>compile</goal>
      <goal>testCompile</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>validate</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
      <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
      <source>
    (new com.kc.Validator()).validate()
      </source>
        </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `<scriptpath>` inside `<configuration>`?

```
<configuration>
  <scriptpath>
    <element>${pom.basedir}/src/test/groovy/com/kc</element>
  </scriptpath>
  <source>......</souce>
</configuration>
```

Refer [Using Groovy Classes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code).

Comment: Is there a way to set the classpath to include all the project runtime or test dependencies?

Comment: Are you facing any problem adding each of them as `<dependency>` in the pom?

Comment: They are already dependencies in the pom.  Do you mean dependencies for this execution?  Isn't there some way to avoid duplicating a large subset of the project dependencies here?  The TestNG plugin doesn't require a separate list of dependencies.

Comment: If all the required dependencies to run the tests are present inside `<dependencies>` with a scope of `runtime` then there should not be any problem running the tests or need of explicitly putting them to the classpath. May be I am misunderstanding here, but if you can elaborate the scenario I would be able to help.

Comment: Basically I want to run a groovy script in the test phase.  The script depends on basically everything the unit tests depend on: all the test-phase dependencies plus classes in src/test.  I am trying to do that via the gmaven-plugin.

Comment: All unit test phase dependencies will automatically be included if they are declared in pom dependencies. For classes under src/test, you can refer [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Building+Groovy+Projects#BuildingGroovyProjects-RunningTests). Again, I am not fully sure if this will suffice the purpose beacause I have not tested this scenario. You can add the `<dependencies>` inside `<plugin>` as well so that it is not affecting the project dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I'm going to isolate the problem and if it's still there I'll edit the question.